# client does not support authentication protocol requested by server consider upgrading mysql client

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to run **python manage.py syncdb** to build a database with Django. However, I get the following error:

> client does not support authentication protocol requested by server consider upgrading mysql client

Then I do this:
[image]

It appears that **FUNCTION mysql.old_password does not exist.**

A section of Django `setting.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'blog_list',
        'USER': 'blog_listuser',
        'PASSWORD': '4cZbmXZyyHpAA0oT',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I use Windows 7 and MySQL 5.7.10.

Here is a part of database log error:

```
2016-02-09T07:55:09.032900Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-02-09T07:55:09.157700Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-02-09T07:55:09.282500Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.10 started; log sequence number 2536368
2016-02-09T07:55:09.282500Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: not started
2016-02-09T07:55:09.547701Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\mysql-5.7.10-win32\data\ib_buffer_pool
2016-02-09T07:55:15.616111Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6381ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=36 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2016-02-09T07:55:17.659715Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-09T07:55:17.690915Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 160209 15:55:17
2016-02-09T07:55:18.985717Z 0 [Warning] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T07:55:19.188518Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-02-09T07:55:19.219718Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2016-02-09T07:55:19.266518Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-02-09T07:55:19.266518Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-02-09T07:55:19.297718Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-02-09T07:55:19.360118Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-02-09T07:55:19.547318Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-02-09T07:55:21.965322Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '*C6E2795BB700C59FE4A4A8E2559543B1AD0263D4' used to authenticate user 'blog_listuser'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2016-02-09T07:55:22.027723Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_leap_second' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T07:55:22.027723Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_name' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T07:55:22.027723Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T07:55:22.027723Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition_type' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T07:55:22.027723Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T07:55:22.090123Z 0 [Warning] System table 'servers' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T07:55:36.317347Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.db: expected column 'User' at position 2 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
2016-02-09T07:55:36.332948Z 0 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 28
2016-02-09T07:55:36.364148Z 0 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
2016-02-09T07:55:36.379748Z 0 [Note] MySQL: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.10'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2016-02-09T09:13:27.113995Z 3 [Warning] The plugin 'mysql_old_password' used to authenticate user 'blog_listuser'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2016-02-09T09:13:27.361009Z 3 [Warning] System table 'servers' is expected to be transactional.
2016-02-09T12:30:51.052347Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 11551607ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't automatically generate your database. You must create it first before syncing or migrating. Also, you need to install `MySQLDB` package on your python package list. But if you're using Python3 then I suggest you use PyMySQL then add these on your `settings.py`

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: I set the permission of mysql with phpmyadmin,and it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, 
I fixed this by replacing `import MySQLdb` with

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

in **settings.py**.

I am using MySQLdb version 1.2.5, PyMySQ version 0.9.2, Python 2.7 and Django 1.11.2.