# (Python) MySQL database Authentication trouble

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, connection

I'm trying to run the code below to add the components of the *symbols* variable into a database called *securities_master*. I posted this question previously and fixed a substantial amount of the errors, however, I am still receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:/Users/Nathan/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 28, in <module>
insert_btc_symbols(symbols)
 File "C:/Users/Nathan/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 15, in insert_btc_symbols
con = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host,user=db_user,db=db_name) #,passwd=db_pass
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 193, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1251, 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried connecting through both a user that has no password, and through the root user along with the public key for the password, both to no avail. The following is the code I am executing:

```
import datetime
import MySQLdb
from math import ceil

def obtain_btc():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    symbols = ['BTC', 'Crypto', 'Bitcoin', 'No Sector', 'USD', now, now]
    return symbols

def insert_btc_symbols(symbols):
    db_host = 'localhost'
    db_user = 'natrob2'
    #db_pass = ''
    db_name = 'securities_master'
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host,user=db_user,db=db_name) #,passwd=db_pass
    column_str = "ticker, instrument, name, sector, currency, created_date, last_updated_date"
    insert_str = (("%s, ")*7)[:2]
    final_str = ("INSERT INTO symbol (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (column_str,insert_str))
    print (final_str,len(symbols))

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        for i in range(0,int(ceil(len(symbols)/100.0))):
            cur.executemany(final_str,symbols[i*100:(i+1)*100-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    symbols = obtain_btc()
    insert_btc_symbols(symbols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the client Endpoint Authentication protocol is not inline with the server.
 could you please try the below-mentioned steps ? 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-client.html

Please see the related issue 
[client does not support authentication protocol requested by server consider upgrading mysql client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294014/client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server-consider-upg)

Comment: I went to try out your suggestion of using the OLD_PASSWORD() function to reset my password to one compatible, but was met with a syntax error telling me to check for the syntax in the manual for my version. Turns out that OLD_PASSWORD() has been removed for MySQL 8.0 …. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by using the command: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
Your answer helped lead me to the right way so thank you.

Comment: hey @Mikey Mike could you explain where you typed in the ALTER USER... query to fix your problem, was it at the mysql prompt, I tried typing it there but all that happened was the arrow prompt ->, I am still having the OperationalError